# How do I use a parameter in where clause of expression in the s3.selectobjectcontent

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, expression

I want to query a csv file present in s3 using SQL expression for which I want to compare the CSV header CustomerId with an outside variable which will be received through an api. How do I compare it in where clause. Here's my code:

```py
import json
import urllib.parse
import io
import boto3
# import requests
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    CustomerId = event["queryStringParameters"]['CustomerId']
    print(CustomerId)
    try:
        resp = s3.select_object_content(
        Bucket='dhanshri-s3-bucket',
        Key='sample_data.csv',
        ExpressionType='SQL',
        Expression="SELECT s.\"List of Recommended Products\" FROM s3object s where s.\"CustomerId\" = CustomerID " ,
        InputSerialization = {'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}, 'CompressionType': 'NONE'},
        OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}},
    )
        

        for event in resp['Payload']:
            if 'Records' in event:
                records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
                print(records)
            elif 'Stats' in event:
                statsDetails = event['Stats']['Details']
                print("Stats details bytesScanned: ")
                print(statsDetails['BytesScanned'])
                print("Stats details bytesProcessed: ")
                print(statsDetails['BytesProcessed'])
                print("Stats details bytesReturned: ")
                print(statsDetails['BytesReturned'])
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.')
        raise e    
    

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": "hello world",
            # "location": ip.text.replace("\n", "")
        }),
    }
```